# Array of dictionaries giving error in a zeep element structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, suds, zeep

I have this element that i have to use as a parameter in a service:

```
ns0:tMensajeEjecucionConsulta(CodConsulta: ns0:tCodConsulta, Parametros: {[({Txt: 
{n: ns0:n, v: ns0:v}} | {Num: {n: ns0:n, v: xsd:decimal}} | {Fec: {n: ns0:n, v: 
xsd:date}} | {Ses: {n: ns0:n, v: ns0:v}})]})
```

I made an object like this:

```
data = {
    'CodConsulta': {'v': '5473'},
    'Parametros': [
        {'Txt': {'n': 'Agente', 'v': 'Test'}},
        {'Fec': {'n': 'Fecha', 'v': '2021-10-28'}},            
    ]}

request = client.get_type('ns0:tMensajeEjecucionConsulta')
data = request(**data)
response = client.service.ServicioEjecucionConsultaEncolumnada(data)
```

`` Parametros() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Txt'. Signature: `[({Txt: {n: {http://www.omel.es/Schemas}n, v: {http://www.omel.es/Schemas}v}} | {Num: {n: {http://www.omel.es/Schemas}n, v: xsd:decimal}} | {Fec: {n: {http://www.omel.es/Schemas}n, v: xsd:date}} | {Ses: {n: {http://www.omel.es/Schemas}n, v: {http://www.omel.es/Schemas}v}})] ``

I've also tried like this:

```
request = client.get_type('ns0:tMensajeEjecucionConsulta')
data = request(CodConsulta='5473', Parametros=[
    {'Txt': {'n': 'Agente', 'v': 'Test'}},
    {'Fec': {'n': 'Fecha', 'v': '2021-10-28'}},
])
response = client.service.ServicioEjecucionConsultaEncolumnada(data)
```

It gave me exactly the same error.

I'm not able to form the object `Parametros` correctly. Can anyone give me an hint why?

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. This element happens to be a `xsd:choice` one. And the structures for that type of element are different from the usual.

The documentation for handling this type of elements is available here:
https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/datastructures.html#xsd-choice

In the end my valid object had to be like this:

```
data = {
    'CodConsulta': {'v': '5473'},
    'Parametros': {'_value_1':
        [
            {'Txt': {'n': 'Agente', 'v': 'Teste'}},
            {'Fec': {'n': 'Fecha', 'v': '2021-10-28'}},
            {'Txt': {'n': 'Sesion', 'v': '0'}}
        ]}}
```